# iCloud features are partially not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, safari, tethering

I reinstalled macOS on my macbook (currently running 10.15.7) and some of the iCloud features stopped working for me. Syncing tabs and history in Safari doesn't work and also Personal Hotspot on iPhone doesn't show up in the WiFi menu on my mac (but works if activated manually.)

Also login to iCloud is painfully slow, asking for my mac or iPhone password several times (as I understand to decrypt data). And such a long login came after I updated my iPhone to iOS 15. Then I rolled back to iOS 14 while it was still possible and had the same problem of long login time, but all functions continue to work on IPhone.

I've tried both logging out of iCloud on all devices, reinstalling the system again, and booting with a new user account. The problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by completely deleting encrypted data in iCloud. I logged out of iCloud on my Mac, then when prompted to enter my iPhone password, I clicked I don't remember it and agreed to the erase (having previously exported passwords from Safari and disabled the iCloud Keychain on my iPhone). I then went through the setup steps, enabled syncing, and imported the saved passwords. And now everything works! Maybe someone could use the method.